# "GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor..." with nonsense signature

Tags: grails, groovy

Grails 3.2.11

I'm trying to define enums to hold my custom defined RoleGroups' and Roles' names and authorities in my service class:

```
import grails.transaction.Transactional

@Transactional
class UserService {

    enum RoleEnum{
        ROLE_SUPERADMIN,
        ROLE_ADMIN,
        ROLE_RECEPTION,
        ROLE_HOUSEKEEPING,
        ;
    }
    enum RoleGroupEnum {
        ROLEGROUP_SUPERADMIN([
            UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_SUPERADMIN,
            UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_ADMIN,
            UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_RECEPTION,
            UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_HOUSEKEEPING
        ]),
        ROLEGROUP_ADMIN([UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_ADMIN]),
        ROLEGROUP_RECEPTION([UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_RECEPTION]),
        ROLEGROUP_HOUSEKEEPING([UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_HOUSEKEEPING]),
        ;

        private List<RoleEnum> roles

        List<RoleEnum> getRoles() {
            return roles
        }

        RoleGroupEnum(List roles) {
            this.roles=roles;
        }
    }


    def serviceMethod() {
        RoleGroupEnum superadmin=RoleGroupEnum.ROLEGROUP_SUPERADMIN;  
       // Throws groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException
    }
}
```

Calling serviceMethod() the following exception is thrown:

```
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: UserService$RoleGroupEnum(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, UserService$RoleEnum)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments1(MetaClassImpl.java:1621)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(MetaClassImpl.java:1537)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.selectConstructorAndTransformArguments(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:238)
    at UserService$RoleGroupEnum.$INIT(UserService.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1426)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.invoke(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.StaticMetaMethodSite.callStatic(StaticMetaMethodSite.java:102)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:194)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:222)
    at UserService$RoleGroupEnum.<clinit>(UserService.groovy:18)
```

I  have no idea where this signature is coming from: `UserService$RoleGroupEnum(java.lang.String, java.lang.Integer, UserService$RoleEnum)`

Just out of curiosity I have added the following constructor:

```
    RoleGroupEnum(String wtf1, Integer wtf2, RoleEnum wtf3) {
        log.debug("WTF");
    }
```

I'm getting the same exception, with the same signature.
Can someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried adding `static` to your enums? ie: `static enum RoleGroupEnum {`  You shouldn't need to, but putting that into the code stops intellij complaining...  BTW; running the above script as a purely groovy class works fine 

Comment: Also, not the issue, but you don't need your semi-colons, and `UserService.RoleEnum.ROLE_SUPERADMIN` can be more easily expressed as `RoleEnum.ROLE_SUPERADMIN`

Comment: I'm using intellij too and it wasn't complaining. However, added `static` and still getting the same exception.

Comment: What happens if you move your enums out of the class into their own class files?

Comment: I have changed RoleGroupEnum the following way: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c4603b3aadbfe667b17546b8f8c67310
Now the exception is gone. I still have no idea what was wrong...